# Implementation of Threads in c++

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm trying to maintain two function with threads in c++ (Visual Studio supporting #include library), when I run function without parameter it runs fine but with parameters it popping up an error. 
Code is:

```
void fun(char a[])
{}

int main()
{
    char arr[4];
    thread t1(fun);
    //(Error    1   error C2198: 'void (__cdecl *)(int [])' : too few arguments for call) 

    thread t2(fun(arr));     
    //Error 1   error C2664: std::thread::thread(std::thread &&) throw()' : 
    //cannot     convert parameter 1 from'void' to 'std::thread &&' 
    //Second Error is 2 IntelliSense: no instance of constructor
    // "std::thread::thread" matches the argument list argument types are: (void

    return 0;
}
```

help me to handle this.

Comment: You should check this on how to properly pass arguments. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is signature of `std::thread` [constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread) (in facti it's a template function):

```
template< class Function, class... Args > 
explicit thread( Function&& f, Args&&... args );
```

It means that you have to provide a [`Callable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Callable) (i.e. anything that you can use `()` on). `fun` is callable, because it is a function. However, expression `fun(arr)` is not, because it denotes function applied to an argument, which yelds type `void` (the return type of `fun`). Moreover, int he expression `thread(fun)` your function is *not* called. It is passed to newly created thread and *then* executed. If expression `thread(fun(arr))` was valid, expression `fun(arr)` would be evaluated *before* new thread was created, and the thread would get only the result of `fun(arr)`, not the function itself.

But C++ Standard Library has got you covered. The beforementioned constructor has a parameter pack (i.e. a variable length list of parameters) named `args` that lets you provide arguments to thread function. So you should use:

```
thread t2(fun, arr);
```

Comment: Initialization of thread in switch statement giving me this error.          "IntelliSense: transfer of control bypasses initialization of:
            variable "id" (declared at line 157)"

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this example:

https://mockstacks.com/Cpp_Threading

```html
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

// The function we want to execute on the new thread.
void task1(string msg)
{
    cout << "task1 says: " << msg;
}

int main()
{
    // Constructs the new thread and runs it. Does not block execution.
    thread t1(task1, "Hello");

    // Do other things...

    // Makes the main thread wait for the new thread to finish execution, therefore blocks its own execution.
    t1.join();
}
```